# FIX protocol print out consecutive spaces. perl

Tags: perl

This is the FIX protocol Log

```
2015-11-19 12:11:34,050INFO [Fix message assembler]TWORDERS42_UBS-<1356 OrderSingle (8=FIX.4.2 9=195 35=D 34=1356 49=TWORDERS42 52=20151119-17:11:34.049 56=UBS 57=PROG 97=N 115=GUARDIAN 11=AFMC286;6CE7-7DF5 15=USD 21=1 22=1 38=4481 40=1 48=031162100 54=1 55=AMGN 59=0 60=20151119-17:01:11 92=CSA 10=028 )
2015-11-19 12:11:34,050INFO [SessionManager for CamUSP3: TWORDERS42 UBS]USA4P3_42_CamUSP3_42->4735 OrderSingle (8=FIX.4.2 9=197 35=D 34=4735 49=TWORDERS42 52=20151119-17:11:34 56=USA4P3_42 57=PROG 97=N 115=GUARDIAN 11=AFMC286;6CE7-7DF5 15=USD 21=1 22=1 38=4481 40=1 48=031162100 54=1 55=AMGN 59=0 60=20151119-17:01:11 92=CSA 10=210 )
2015-11-19 12:12:54,468INFO [Fix message assembler]USA4P3_42_CamUSP3_42-<68210 ExecutionReport (8=FIX.4.2 9=285 35=8 34=68210 52=20151119-17:12:54 43=N 49=USA4P3_42 50=PROG 56=TWORDERS42 128=GUARDIAN 20=0 151=4481 150=0 11=AFMC286;6CE7-7DF5 31=0.0000 32=0 21=1 15=USD 59=0 55=AMGN 22=1 48=031162100 54=1 39=0 38=4481 40=1 37=42348647 17=842696664 6=0.0000000 14=0 60=20151119-17:12:54 75=20151119 10=099 )
2015-11-19 12:12:54,468INFO [SessionManager for CamUSP3: USA4P3_42 CamUSP3_42]TWORDERS42_UBS->9012 ExecutionReport (8=FIX.4.2 9=278 35=8 34=9012 52=20151119-17:12:54 43=N 49=UBS 50=PROG 56=TWORDERS42 128=GUARDIAN 20=0 151=4481 150=0 11=AFMC286;6CE7-7DF5 31=0.0000 32=0 21=1 15=USD 59=0 55=AMGN 22=1 48=031162100 54=1 39=0 38=4481 40=1 37=42348647 17=842696664 6=0.0000000 14=0 60=20151119-17:12:54 75=20151119 10=181 )
2015-11-19 12:13:58,300INFO [Fix message assembler]USA4P3_42_CamUSP3_42-<68476 ExecutionReport (8=FIX.4.2 9=303 35=8 34=68476 52=20151119-17:13:58 43=N 49=USA4P3_42 50=PROG 56=TWORDERS42 128=GUARDIAN 20=0 151=4381 150=1 11=AFMC286;6CE7-7DF5 29=1 31=159.0800 32=100 30=O 21=1 15=USD 59=0 55=AMGN 22=1 48=031162100 54=1 39=1 38=4481 40=1 37=42348647 17=842697795 6=159.0800000 14=100 60=20151119-17:13:58 75=20151119 10=243 )
2015-11-19 12:13:58,300INFO [SessionManager for CamUSP3: USA4P3_42 CamUSP3_42]TWORDERS42_UBS->9061 ExecutionReport (8=FIX.4.2 9=296 35=8 34=9061 52=20151119-17:13:58 43=N 49=UBS 50=PROG 56=TWORDERS42 128=GUARDIAN 20=0 151=4381 150=1 11=AFMC286;6CE7-7DF5 29=1 31=159.0800 32=100 30=O 21=1 15=USD 59=0 55=AMGN 22=1 48=031162100 54=1 39=1 38=4481 40=1 37=42348647 17=842697795 6=159.0800000 14=100 60=20151119-17:13:58 75=20151119 10=068 )
2015-11-19 12:14:16,245INFO [Fix message assembler]USA4P3_42_CamUSP3_42-<68598 ExecutionReport (8=FIX.4.2 9=304 35=8 34=68598 52=20151119-17:14:16 43=N 49=USA4P3_42 50=PROG 56=TWORDERS42 128=GUARDIAN 20=0 151=4281 150=1 11=AFMC286;6CE7-7DF5 29=2 31=159.0850 32=100 30=65 21=1 15=USD 59=0 55=AMGN 22=1 48=031162100 54=1 39=1 38=4481 40=1 37=42348647 17=842698178 6=159.0825000 14=200 60=20151119-17:14:16 75=20151119 10=020 )



#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict ;
use warnings ;



my $filename = "/tmp/foo" ;

open(my $fh, '<', $filename)
or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

my @fixString = " ";

while (my $row = <$fh>) {
chomp $row;

my @line = split("\s", "$row");
foreach my $line(@line) {
if ($line =~ /56=(\w+)/ ) {
$fixString[3] = "$1" ;
}
foreach $line(@line) {
if ($line =~ /49=(\w+)/ ) {
$fixString[2] = "From $1 to " ;
}
#sleep 1 ;
}


}

print "@fixString\n" ;
}
```

For some reason When i use the "\s" as the splitter, It splits on the "s" - I thought that the regex for space is "\s"

```
From TWORDERS42 to  ca
From TWORDERS42 to  USA4P3_42
From USA4P3_42 to  TWORDERS42
From ca to  TWORDERS42
From USA4P3_42 to  TWORDERS42
From ca to  TWORDERS42
From USA4P3_42 to  TWORDERS42
From ca to  TWORDERS42
From USA4P3_42 to  TWORDERS42
From ca to  TWORDERS42
From USA4P3_42 to  TWORDERS42
From ca to  TWORDERS42
From USA4P3_42 to  TWORDERS42
From USA4P3_42 to  TWORDERS42
From ca to  TWORDERS42
From ca to  TWORDERS42
From USA4P3_42 to  TWORDERS42
```

ANyhow when i replace the "\s" with a " " it gets better -

```
From TWORDERS42 to  casperbank
From TWORDERS42 to  USA4P3_42
From USA4P3_42 to  TWORDERS42
From casperbank to  TWORDERS42
From USA4P3_42 to  TWORDERS42
From casperbank to  TWORDERS42
From USA4P3_42 to  TWORDERS42
From casperbank to  TWORDERS42
From USA4P3_42 to  TWORDERS42
From casperbank to  TWORDERS42
From USA4P3_42 to  TWORDERS42
From casperbank to  TWORDERS42
From USA4P3_42 to  TWORDERS42
From USA4P3_42 to  TWORDERS42
From casperbank to  TWORDERS42
From casperbank to  TWORDERS42
From USA4P3_42 to  TWORDERS42
```

What I want is consistent spaces between the print outs.  Is there a way to do this whilst printing from an array ?

```
From TWORDERS42 to  casperbank
From TWORDERS42 to  USA4P3_42
From USA4P3_42  to  TWORDERS42
From casperbank to  TWORDERS42
From USA4P3_42  to  TWORDERS42
From casperbank to  TWORDERS42
From USA4P3_42  to  TWORDERS42
From casperbank to  TWORDERS42
From USA4P3_42  to  TWORDERS42
From casperbank to  TWORDERS42
From USA4P3_42  to  TWORDERS42
From casperbank to  TWORDERS42
From USA4P3_42  to  TWORDERS42
From USA4P3_42  to  TWORDERS42
From casperbank to  TWORDERS42
From casperbank to  TWORDERS42
From USA4P3_42  to  TWORDERS42
```

Answer (score 2):

To print in a consistent way you could use [printf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html):

`printf("%-5s %-11s %s %s", $line[0], $line[1], $line[2], $line[3]);`

This way you introduce the necesary blank space to aling them. Or you could do `print join("\t" @line);`

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple mistakes, inefficiencies, redundancies, etc. in your code, which can actually be solved simply by reverting to Perl's default behaviors and/or shortcuts. By default, many of the builtin functions operate on `$_`, which we can take advantage of to simplify and shorten our code. Taking it a step further, `split()`, when provided a pattern of `' '` (or no pattern at all!) automatically treats the pattern as `/\s+/`. I've also used a hash to store any `key=value` pairs we find, which gives us flexibility later on if we decide we want to access different pieces of the data.

Putting it all together, here's an alternate way to approach your problem:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @fields = split;
    my %values;

    for (@fields) {
        my @parts = split(/=/);
        next unless scalar(@parts) == 2;
        $values{$parts[0]} = $parts[1];
    }

    printf("From %-13s to    %s\n", $values{49}, $values{56});
}

__DATA__
2015-11-19 12:11:34,050INFO [Fix message assembler]TWORDERS42_UBS-<1356 OrderSingle (8=FIX.4.2 9=195 35=D 34=1356 49=TWORDERS42 52=20151119-17:11:34.049 56=UBS 57=PROG 97=N 115=GUARDIAN 11=AFMC286;6CE7-7DF5 15=USD 21=1 22=1 38=4481 40=1 48=031162100 54=1 55=AMGN 59=0 60=20151119-17:01:11 92=CSA 10=028 )
2015-11-19 12:11:34,050INFO [SessionManager for CamUSP3: TWORDERS42 UBS]USA4P3_42_CamUSP3_42->4735 OrderSingle (8=FIX.4.2 9=197 35=D 34=4735 49=TWORDERS42 52=20151119-17:11:34 56=USA4P3_42 57=PROG 97=N 115=GUARDIAN 11=AFMC286;6CE7-7DF5 15=USD 21=1 22=1 38=4481 40=1 48=031162100 54=1 55=AMGN 59=0 60=20151119-17:01:11 92=CSA 10=210 )
2015-11-19 12:12:54,468INFO [Fix message assembler]USA4P3_42_CamUSP3_42-<68210 ExecutionReport (8=FIX.4.2 9=285 35=8 34=68210 52=20151119-17:12:54 43=N 49=USA4P3_42 50=PROG 56=TWORDERS42 128=GUARDIAN 20=0 151=4481 150=0 11=AFMC286;6CE7-7DF5 31=0.0000 32=0 21=1 15=USD 59=0 55=AMGN 22=1 48=031162100 54=1 39=0 38=4481 40=1 37=42348647 17=842696664 6=0.0000000 14=0 60=20151119-17:12:54 75=20151119 10=099 )
2015-11-19 12:12:54,468INFO [SessionManager for CamUSP3: USA4P3_42 CamUSP3_42]TWORDERS42_UBS->9012 ExecutionReport (8=FIX.4.2 9=278 35=8 34=9012 52=20151119-17:12:54 43=N 49=UBS 50=PROG 56=TWORDERS42 128=GUARDIAN 20=0 151=4481 150=0 11=AFMC286;6CE7-7DF5 31=0.0000 32=0 21=1 15=USD 59=0 55=AMGN 22=1 48=031162100 54=1 39=0 38=4481 40=1 37=42348647 17=842696664 6=0.0000000 14=0 60=20151119-17:12:54 75=20151119 10=181 )
2015-11-19 12:13:58,300INFO [Fix message assembler]USA4P3_42_CamUSP3_42-<68476 ExecutionReport (8=FIX.4.2 9=303 35=8 34=68476 52=20151119-17:13:58 43=N 49=USA4P3_42 50=PROG 56=TWORDERS42 128=GUARDIAN 20=0 151=4381 150=1 11=AFMC286;6CE7-7DF5 29=1 31=159.0800 32=100 30=O 21=1 15=USD 59=0 55=AMGN 22=1 48=031162100 54=1 39=1 38=4481 40=1 37=42348647 17=842697795 6=159.0800000 14=100 60=20151119-17:13:58 75=20151119 10=243 )
2015-11-19 12:13:58,300INFO [SessionManager for CamUSP3: USA4P3_42 CamUSP3_42]TWORDERS42_UBS->9061 ExecutionReport (8=FIX.4.2 9=296 35=8 34=9061 52=20151119-17:13:58 43=N 49=UBS 50=PROG 56=TWORDERS42 128=GUARDIAN 20=0 151=4381 150=1 11=AFMC286;6CE7-7DF5 29=1 31=159.0800 32=100 30=O 21=1 15=USD 59=0 55=AMGN 22=1 48=031162100 54=1 39=1 38=4481 40=1 37=42348647 17=842697795 6=159.0800000 14=100 60=20151119-17:13:58 75=20151119 10=068 )
2015-11-19 12:14:16,245INFO [Fix message assembler]USA4P3_42_CamUSP3_42-<68598 ExecutionReport (8=FIX.4.2 9=304 35=8 34=68598 52=20151119-17:14:16 43=N 49=USA4P3_42 50=PROG 56=TWORDERS42 128=GUARDIAN 20=0 151=4281 150=1 11=AFMC286;6CE7-7DF5 29=2 31=159.0850 32=100 30=65 21=1 15=USD 59=0 55=AMGN 22=1 48=031162100 54=1 39=1 38=4481 40=1 37=42348647 17=842698178 6=159.0825000 14=200 60=20151119-17:14:16 75=20151119 10=020 )
```

Output:

```
From TWORDERS42    to    UBS
From TWORDERS42    to    USA4P3_42
From USA4P3_42     to    TWORDERS42
From UBS           to    TWORDERS42
From USA4P3_42     to    TWORDERS42
From UBS           to    TWORDERS42
From USA4P3_42     to    TWORDERS42
```

This works fine for inline data, which is great for examples, but not so great for real life. Well, Perl makes it easy to process files, too: just delete the `__DATA__` section at the bottom and change `while (<DATA>)` to `while (<>)`.

You can then run your script like this:

```
perl myscript.pl file1.log file2.log file3.log [...]
```

If you expect the width of the first column to be highly dynamic, you could do something like this, but I think it's overkill for this example, and I'd prefer to just use "engineering judgement" instead.

```
use List::Util qw(max);

my @data;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @fields = split;
    my %values;

    for (@fields) {
        my @parts = split(/=/);
        next unless scalar(@parts) == 2;
        $values{$parts[0]} = $parts[1];
    }

    push(@data, \%values);
}

my $max = max(map { length($_->{49}) } @data);

for (@data) {
    printf("From %-*s to    %s\n", $max + 3, $_->{49}, $_->{56});
}
```